# Program thinks for a while and just says killed

Tags: python

I've only been using python for a few days and am writing a program that takes a csv file and a txt file from command line.  The csv file contains names and a number that is the longest sequence of a type of DNA (example John, 26, 45, 23).  The txt file contains a set of dna which is basically a string of char.  I need to put the csv file into a list of lists then the txt file into a variable.  A function I'm given will return an int for the longest occurrence of that strand.  I run that function three times to get my 3 ints to compare.  Currently my below program when I run it just sits a while then says: killed.

```py
import csv
import sys


def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Missing Files!")
        sys.exit(1)
    # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    dnalist = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline = ''):
        dnalist = list(csv.reader(sys.argv[1]))
        for row_list in dnalist:
            dnalist.append(row_list)

    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as f:
        sequence = f.read()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    chdnalist = []
    subsequence = "AGAT"
    chdnalist[0] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)
    subsequence = "AATG"
    chdnalist[1] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)
    subsequence = "TATC"
    chdnalist[2] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)

    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    for i in range (0, len(dnalist)):
        if dnalist[i][1] == chdnalist[0] and dnalist[i][2] == chdnalist[1] and dnalist[i][3] == chdnalist[2]:
            print (dnalist[i][0])
            return
    print ("No Match")
    return


def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run


main()
```

This is the contents of the txt file:
AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG

Comment: When python exits and prints `KILLED` it generally means your program ran out of memory for whatever it's attempting to compute.

Comment: how large is that text file?

Comment: The txt file is 161 characters.  The csv file im currently using is 4 lines and the bigger one I havent tried yet is 24.

Comment: @Scout_vet would be nice if you provided the contents of that text file so that we can run your code ourselves

Comment: I edited my post to contain the contents of the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your code placing print statements at various locations in your program.  I found out quickly that the program was getting stuck on this block of code.

```
 with open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline = ''):
    dnalist = list(csv.reader(sys.argv[1]))
    for row_list in dnalist:
        dnalist.append(row_list)
```

This was the bit that kept consuming memory until you got that "KILL" notification.  Reviewing other examples on how to read in data from a CSV file, I did a bit of tweaking to your code regarding the import of the CSV data along with defining your dna match lists.  Following is a copy of the tweaked version.

```
import csv
import sys

def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Missing Files!")
        sys.exit(1)
    # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    dnalist = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", newline = '') as subject_file:      # Refactored this bit
        dnalst = csv.reader(subject_file)
        for row_list in dnalst:
            dnalist.append(row_list)

    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as f:
        sequence = f.read()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    chdnalist = [[],[],[]]                      # Needed to define this as an arrary of lists
    subsequence = "AGAT"
    chdnalist[0] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)
    subsequence = "AATG"
    chdnalist[1] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)
    subsequence = "TATC"
    chdnalist[2] = longest_match(sequence, subsequence)

    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    for i in range (0, len(dnalist)):
        if dnalist[i][1] == chdnalist[0] and dnalist[i][2] == chdnalist[1] and dnalist[i][3] == chdnalist[2]:
            print (dnalist[i][0])
            return
    print ("No Match")
    return

def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)
    
    print(sequence_length)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length - 1):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run


main()
```

I put a couple of comments in there to point at the changes made.

Just to try it out, I created a simple bit of subject data in a CSV file and created that text file.  Following was the output I got.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/DNA$ python3 DNA.py "Subjects.csv" "DNA.txt"
171
171
171
No Match
```

In the big picture, there weren't a lot of changes, so this should match up to the spirit of your project.  Anyway, test that out and see if that allows you to move forward.